# Parsing whitespaces with waxeye generated parser

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, parser-generator, waxeye

I'm using waxeye parser generator to generate python parser for some grammar. Unfortunately when I try to parse any text I almost every time get the same error:

```
parse error: failed to match 'whitespace' at line=1, col=10, pos=10
```

or

```
parse error: failed to match 'ws' at line=1, col=10, pos=10
```

I suppose it's problem with my definition of grammar, but I tried almost every way I could make up and it's still wrong.

Here's python code:

```
import waxeye
import robLang
text = ' block is red '


def analyze(input):
    ast = robLang.Parser().parse(input)
    if isinstance(ast, waxeye.ParseError):
        return ast
    else:
        return sum(ast.children[0])

result = analyze(text)
print result
```

and grammar definition:

```
statement <- ws thing ws isWord wse adjective ws ?(adjectives)

thing <- objectType ?(ws name)

objectType <- 'pyramid'|'ball'|'block'|'boot'|'leg'|'degree'

name <- [a-zA-Z] *[a-zA-Z0-9_-]

isWord <- 'is'

adjectives <- *(adjective ws)

colour <- 'red'|'green'|'blue'|'black'|'white'|'yellow'|'orange'|'purple'
        |'cyan'|'magenta'

size <- 'small'|'big'

moralDirection <- 'good'|'bad'

adjective <- colour|size|moralDirection

number <- +[0-9] ?('.' +[0-9]) ws

ws <: *[ \t\n\r]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
statement <- ws thing ws isWord wse adjective ws ?(adjectives)
```

Change `wse` into `ws`.